# Can not import module validator in NextJS 13

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I ran into some weird issue with importing module. Nextjs says this:

```
./application/sign_in/sign_in_store.ts:2:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'validator'
  1 | import { createEvent, createStore } from "effector"
> 2 | import validator from "validator"
  3 | 
  4 | interface SignInStore {
  5 |   email: string

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./app/prihlaseni/page.tsx
```

I do not know what happened, it worked... I am just unable to include this module, I tried everything from deleting package-lock.json to installing and uninstalling this dependency back and forth.

```
import { createEvent, createStore } from "effector"
import validator from "validator"

interface SignInStore {
  email: string
  password: string
  showEmailErrorMessage: boolean
  showPasswordErrorMessage: boolean
  signInButtonEnabled: boolean
}
export const emailChanged = createEvent<string>()
export const passwordChanged = createEvent<string>()
export const signInRequested = createEvent()
export default createStore<SignInStore>({
  email: "",
  password: "",
  showEmailErrorMessage: false,
  showPasswordErrorMessage: false,
  signInButtonEnabled: false,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i fixed it by running npm i validator and later on running npm install validator in my terminal and it worked.